# How to get the currently logged in user (from auth) and display his name on the post

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How can I get the Username and save it to auhtor model in discussion and then display it in template. i tried a few things but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. thanks

**models**

```
class  Discussion(models.Model):
    author=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    argument=models.CharField(max_length=350)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=31,unique=True)
    created_on=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('discussion_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Form**

```
class DiscussionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Discussion
        fields=['title','argument','slug']
```

**Views:**

```
class NewDiscussionView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    template_name='Discussion/new_discussion.html'
    form_class= DiscussionForm
    def get(self,request):
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form': self.form_class()})
    def post(self,request):
        bound_form = self.form_class(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_discussion=bound_form.save()
            return render(request,'Discussion/discussion.html',{'discussion':Discussion.objects.all()})
        else:
            return render(request,self.template_name,{'form': bound_form})
```

Comment: `request.user.username` should give you back the username as string

Comment: that i know but how do i save it to the model..it doesn't work when i simply try to update the author field before saving the form

Comment: Since its not in in your form fields, after the `is_valid` check, you will need to add `bound_form.instance.author = request.user.username`. Hopefully this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution as implied by [devdob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3140312/devdob)

```
class NewDiscussionView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    template_name='Discussion/new_discussion.html'
    form_class= DiscussionForm
    def get(self,request):
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form': self.form_class()})
    def post(self,request):
        bound_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            bound_form.instance.author = request.user.username #Solution
            new_discussion=bound_form.save()
            return render(request,'Discussion/discussion.html',{'discussion':Discussion.objects.all()})
        else:
            return render(request,self.template_name,{'form': bound_form})
```